# Converting update statement values dynamically in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to convert the value in the update statement dynamically in SQL Server.

For example, if I receive value as 'true', need to convert it as 'enabled' and 'false', then convert it as 'disabled'.

How I need to implement this in SQL Server ?

Comment: Your are familiar with case-statement?

Comment: _" if I receive value as ..."_ means what exactly? Is your goal to implement some sort of logic within sql server to intercept SQL queries and "translate" part of them before insert or update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't "conversion"; conversion means when you change the data type of a value, such as from a `varchar` to an `int`.

What you want here is simply a `CASE` expression:

```sql
CASE YourValue WHEN 'true' THEN 'enabled'
               WHEN 'false' THEN 'disabled'
END
```

You could also use an `IIF()`, which parsed as a `CASE` expression "under the hood":

```sql
IIF(YourValue = 'true','enabled','false')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works correctly.